# How do I pass a URL containing an equals sign to explorer.exe?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, special-characters

I've tried running

```
prompt> explorer.exe "https://www.google.com/search?q=example"
```

, but it just opens a normal explorer window.

```
prompt> explorer.exe "https://www.example.com/?q"
```

works. It seems the culprit is the `=` character.

I've tried escaping it with a backslash and `^`, but that doesn't work either.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that explorer.exe requires wrapping the argument in quotes to escape these characters inside. Since the example uses PowerShell, this can be achieved like this:

```
explorer.exe """https://google.com/search?q=search"""
```

or

```
explorer.exe "`"https://google.com/search?q=hcraes`""
```

Comment: You are a rockstar